# What are the differences between these two .htaccess code?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

So I've searched very hard on trying to understand the differences between these two pieces of code, but I could not find it. I am trying to remove the ".html" extension from the url but I always see two different codes being used from different websites.

The first code is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The second code is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html
```

From my understanding the first code seems to replace any characters that used to be in that .html path (eg. example.com/home.html) to replace it without the .html extension (eg. example.com/home). Both seems to keep coming up however, in many different websites. That is why I would like to ask if anyone know the differences between the both and what both of these pieces of codes actually mean?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The first matches any request for a path ending in `.html` and tells the browser that it should ask for the same path, on `example.com` *without* the `.html`.

The second matches any request for any path and tells the server to add `.html` to the end of it and deliver that to the browser.

Comment: That is also what I thought but in many websites they said that the second code is to remove the .html at the end of it.

Comment: That's true, from a certain point of view. It makes the URL without `.html` on the end of it work.

Comment: So technically both codes would work? Or is the first one more reliable?

Comment: I mean does both work for removing the .html extensions?

Comment: Yes … for different interpretations of that sentence. Go back and reread the answer where I explained the difference.